# Как настроить вывод и сортировку категорий по иерархии в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cms, woocommerce

Добрый вечер,
Использую сайт на WordPress. На сайте используются плагины WooCommerce и All in one SEO. 
Сайт работает как интернет магазин с каталогом товаров. На сайте существуют категории и подкатегории товаров.

В title и в описание (файл meta.php в single-product, в шаблонах плагина WooCommerce), выдаётся список категорий конкретного товара.

К сожалению список категорий выдаётся в алфавитном порядке. Подскажите пожалуйста что прописать в functions.php, чтобы сортировка была по slug или по Id категорий.

*P.S
В исходном коде meta.php вывод категорий выглядит так:

`$cat_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );`

`<?php echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', $cat_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Здесь скорее надо менять не functions.php, а вывод списка категорий в шаблоне.

Например,

```
wp_list_categories ('orderby=slug')
```

Подробнее о всех параметрах тут - https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_categories

Либо взять плагин https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/

Comment: В WooCommerce не категории, а таксономии. Этот ответ работать не будет.

Comment: В описании плагина - Order Categories and all custom taxonomies terms.

Comment: В исходном коде все выглядит так:

`$cat_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );`

`<?php echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', $cat_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>`

Comment: get_categories - выдает вам список в алфавитном порядке из массива ( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', $cat_count, 'woocommerce' ). 
 Чтобы сортировать по-другому, добавьте в нужное место orderby и параметр сортировки (id, slug или что еще).

Comment: где это самое нужное место? в этом и суть вопроса